# What is the relative performance of 1 geometry column vs 4 decimals in Sql Server 2008?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, geometry, sql-server-2008-r2, spatial

I need to represent the dimensions of a piece of a <strike>quadrilateral</strike> rectangle surface in a SQL Server 2008 database.  I will need to perform queries based on the distance between different points and the total area of the surface.

**Will my performance be better using a geometry datatype or 4 decimal columns?**  Why?

If the geometry datatype is unnecessary in this situation, what amount of complexity in the geometrical shape would be required for using the geometry datatype to make sense?

Comment: It sounds like *you* have enough information in your possession to be able to set up representative data and queries and determine which performs better - we don't. Performance questions aren't generally answerable in the abstract.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I agree that specific performance questions need to be answered in their specific context, but I think comparing the speed of working with two different types is general enough for this question.  One would be justified in saying that "In general, it's faster faster to query against an `int` column than a `varchar(255)` column", and I don't really see how this is different.

Comment: Mostly, because I have no idea *what* you're planning to store in those 4 decimal columns - you started with talking about a quadrilateral - if I was going to store one as decimals, I'd have thought I'd be storing 4 coordinates, so 8 columns would be required. You obviously have some design in mind that means that 4 columns will work for your specific situation, but I've no idea what that design is...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, They are actually rectangles, I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used the geometry datatype, and have never had reason to read up on it. Even so, it seems to me that if you’re just doing basic arithmatic on a simple geometric object, the mundane old SQL datatypes should be quite effiicient, particularly if you toss in some calculated columns for frequently used calculations.

For example:

```
--DROP TABLE MyTable
CREATE TABLE MyTable
 (
   X1  decimal  not null
  ,Y1  decimal  not null
  ,X2  decimal  not null
  ,Y2  decimal  not null
  ,Area as abs((X2-X1) * (Y2-Y1))
  ,XLength as abs((X2 - X1))
  ,YLength as abs((Y2 - Y1))
  ,Diagonal as sqrt(power(abs((X2 - X1)), 2) + power(abs((Y2 - Y1)), 2))
 )

INSERT MyTable values (1,1,4,5)
INSERT MyTable values (4,5,1,1)
INSERT MyTable values (0,0,3,3)

SELECT * from MyTable
```

Ugly calculations, but they won’t be performed unless and until they are actually referenced (or unless you choose to index them). I have no statistics, but performing the same operations via the Geometry datatype *probably* means accessing rarely used mathematical subroutines, possibly embedded in system CLR assemblies, and I just can’t see that being significantly faster than the bare-bones SQL arithmatic routines.

I just took a look in BOL on the Geometry datatype. (a) Zounds! (b) Cool! Check out the entries under “geomety Data Type Method Reference” ([online here](http://ms-help://MS.SQLCC.v10/MS.SQLSVR.v10.en/s10de_6tsql/html/d88e632b-6b2f-4466-a15f-9fbef1a347a7.htm) , but you want to look at the expanded treeview under this entry.) If that’s the kind of functionality you’ll be needing, by all means use the Geometry data type, but for simple processing, I’d stick with the knucklescraper datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

the geometry data types are more complex than simple decimals so there just be an overhead.  But they do provide functions that calculate distance between two points and i would assume these have been optermised.  The question might be if you implemented the distance between points logic - would this take longer than having the data in appropriate format in the first place.

As every DB question might relate to the ratio of inserts v selects/calc's

Comment: The only user who will create records that contain these columns will be the administrator,  But, they will be queried by all users.  (A lot more selects + calcs than inserts)

Comment: Then i would have thought using the built in functionality should give you better performance.  I have no proof of ths, so would be interested to see what people answer on this one :-)

Comment: I would think the opposite.  My reasoning is that my use case is on the extreme lower end of supported complexity for the data type.  The datatype's infrastructure allows a lot and it's possible that the cost of creating a data instance might be larger than the built-in optimization of the query logic.

Answer (score -4):

`Geometry` datatype is Spatial and `decimal` isn't,

Spatial vs. Non-spatial Data

Spatial data includes location, shape, size, and orientation.
For example, consider a particular square:
its center (the intersection of its diagonals) specifies its location
its shape is a square
the length of one of its sides specifies its size
the angle its diagonals make with, say, the x-axis specifies its orientation.
Spatial data includes spatial relationships.  For example, the arrangement of ten bowling pins is spatial data.

Non-spatial data (also called attribute or characteristic data) is that information which is independent of all geometric considerations.
For example, a person?s height, mass, and age are non-spatial data because they are independent of the person?s location.
It?s interesting to note that, while mass is non-spatial data, weight is spatial data in the sense that something?s weight is very much dependent on its location!

It is possible to ignore the distinction between spatial and non-spatial data.  However, there are fundamental differences between them:
spatial data are generally multi-dimensional and autocorrelated.
non-spatial data are generally one-dimensional and independent.

These distinctions put spatial and non-spatial data into different philosophical camps with far-reaching implications for conceptual, processing, and storage issues.
For example, sorting is perhaps the most common and important non-spatial data processing function that is performed.
It is not obvious how to even sort locational data such that all points end up ?nearby? their nearest neighbors.

These distinctions justify a separate consideration of spatial and non-spatial data models.  This unit limits its attention to the latter unless otherwise specified.

Here's some more if you're interested:
http://www.ncgia.ucsb.edu/giscc/units/u045/u045_f.html

Heres a link i found about Benchmarking Spatial Data Warehouses: http://hpc.ac.upc.edu/Talks/dir08/T000327/paper.pdf

Comment: question about performance really - but very clear comparison between types

Comment: Zee Tee, I already understand everything you just posted.  My question is not about the difference between `geometry` and `decimal`, but between the relative performance of using them in an application.  My object model represents the data as spatial, but my use case is simple enough that I could effectively use 4 `decimal` columns to represent the model.  If performance were not a concern, I would use `geometry`, because it is a more accurate representation, but I am willing to write the extra code for my queries if there is a significant performance difference.

Comment: Heres a link i found about Benchmarking Spatial Data Warehouses: http://hpc.ac.upc.edu/Talks/dir08/T000327/paper.pdf

Comment: That article is pretty dense, so I might have missed something when I skimmed it but it looks like it is suggesting a procedure to benchmark spatial data warehouses.  I'm looking for something more along the lines of comparing benchmarks of spatial-data=usage to benchmarks of non-spatial-data-usage.